# Feedback on Admin set user as mod in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm a beginner to Rails and is following Michael Hartl's book. In chapter 9, where he set up an Admin role, and admin can delete users. I want to extend this feature by allowing admin to set users to Mod as well.

The plan is this:

1.An logged in admin go to the users page, where he sees a list of users(users_url)

2.And next to their name, the admin have an option of 'Set Mod', when the admin clicks that, it sets the user's mod attribute to true.

```
$ rails g migration add_mod_to_users mod:boolean
```

then in the migrated file, set default to false, and

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

In the routes.rb

```
get 'setmod' => 'users#setmod'
```

and in users_controller.rb

```
def setmod
  if logged_in? && current_user.admin?
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attribute(:mod, true) 
    flash[:success] = "User ID #{@user.id} is now a mod!"
    redirect_to users_url
  else
    flash[:warning] = "You can't do that!"
    redirect_to users_url
  end
end
```

In the list of users view file:

```
<% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to "Set Mod", setmod_path(:id => user.id) %>
```

Is this the right approach to it? I'm a beginner so i'd be glad if i can get some feedback on this. Does my code have any vulnerable spots? What's a better way doing it?

Also, i tried to do some test on this
in test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb

```
  # This test passes
  test "should redirect setmod when not logged in" do
    get :setmod
    assert_redirected_to users_url
  end

  # This test failed
  test "should redirect setmod when logged in as a non-admin" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    assert_no_difference '@user.mod' do
      get :setmod, id: @user
    end
    assert flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to users_url
  end
```

I know the second test's code is wrong, but i can't figure out the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing a user id into the `setmod` route.

Change to this:

```
get 'setmod/:id' => 'users#setmod'
```

Now, navigating to `http://localhost:3000/setmod/1` will attempt to set the user (with id=1) to mod.

However, you can use Rails' built-in resources to handle this just fine.

*routes.rb*

```
resources :users
```

*your view*

```
link_to("Promote the user to MOD", user_path(@user, status: 1), method: :put)
```

Clicking that link will update the single attribute for a user shown on the page. You would simply authenticate the admin in the `users_controller.rb` `update` action.

Comment: right now the route is /setmod?=1, and i'm using the two methods(logged_in? && current_user.admin?) from the railstutorial book to limit people who have access to it, is this secure enough?

Comment: I honestly cannot say without seeing the source of those methods. I would recommend at least changing the `get 'setmod'` to a `post` or `put` request though

Comment: So there's GET, POST AND PUT, which one do you think i should use in this case? Thanks for helping me btw

Comment: You can use built-in rails resources to update a user. I'll edit my answer